# Can I have an inset shadow along the bottom of a div only?

Tags: css

Can I have an inset shadow along the bottom of a div only? I've been playing with the box-shadow property in CSS3 for a while and cant figure out how to go about doing this.

I can get it to show on the inside along the top of the div but cant figure out how to get it to the bottom. I haven't been able to find any topics relating to this.. is it possible?

```
box-shadow: inset 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use negative distances to more the shadow to the left or up (therefore having them on the right and bottom edges for inset shadows).

Comment: Ah of course, thank you! I ended up using this if anyone else is trying to do this: `box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);`